# Include with projection does not work

Tags: include, entity-framework-4.1, projection

I have this query

```
    var test = context.Assignments
        .Include(a => a.Customer)
        .Include(a => a.Subscriptions)
        .Select(a => new AssignmentWithSubscriptionCount { SubscriptionCount = a.Subscriptions.Count(), Assignment = a })
        .ToList();

    var name = test.First().Assignment.Customer.Name;
```

It failes to eagerly load Customer, I've seen similar problems here on stackoverflow and it looks like you cant use projections with include. But I have not found a solution to my problem.. Anyone?

edit: Here is a eager load with projection that work, its more complex than the example above so I cant for my life understand whats wrong, thanks.

```
    var test = context.PublicationStateGroups
        .Include(p => p.PublicationStates.Select(ps => ps.AllowedPublicationStateActions.Select(aps => aps.PublicationStateAction)))
        .Select(psg => new StateAndGroupInfo
        {
            ShowReport = psg.PublicationStates.Any(p => p.PublicationStateReportTypeId.HasValue),
            Actions = psg.PublicationStates.SelectMany(state => state.AllowedPublicationStateActions)
                .Select(a => a.PublicationStateAction)
                .Distinct()
        }).ToList();

    var eagerTest = test.First().Actions.First().Name;
```

Comment: The second example is different to your first example. In the second you only access an element in the `Actions` collection which is directly a member in your projected object. In the first you try to access a navigation property `Assignment.Customer` on the projected member `Assignment` which doesn't work. You can remove the `Include` in both examples, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ah, that is correct :D So you tell me that EF is such an unmature product that I cant do this and keep the relations on the mapped object? I told my team members we should have choosen nHibernate but they didnt wanna listen :/

Comment: Yes, `Include` in projections is not supported, as far as I am aware of. It also seems to be confirmed by MS (see Ladislav's answer below). My answer is just a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the customer to your projection:

```cs
var test = context.Assignments
    .Select(a => new AssignmentWithSubscriptionCount
    {
        SubscriptionCount = a.Subscriptions.Count(),
        Assignment = a,
        Customer = a.Customer
    });

var name = test.First().Customer.Name;
```

The EF context will probably ensure that `Assignment.Customer` gets populated automatically.

**Edit**

If you don't want or can't change the `AssignmentWithSubscriptionCount` class you can also project into an anonymous type and then copy the result in memory into this class:

```cs
var test = context.Assignments
    .Select(a => new
    {
        SubscriptionCount = a.Subscriptions.Count(),
        Assignment = a,
        Customer = a.Customer
    });

test.ToList() // executes query
    .Select(o =>
    {
        o.Assignment.Customer = o.Customer;
        return new AssignmentWithSubscriptionCount
        {
            SubscriptionCount = o.SubscriptionCount,
            Assignment = o.Assignment
        }
    });
```

Another option is explicite loading (requires one additional roundtrip per loaded `Assignment` though).

Comment: There must be a better solution than that?

Comment: @Anders: I have *another* solution (see my Edit) but is it *better*? You don't need to change your projection class with the second way - if that is it what you don't like with the first option.

Comment: No, it feels like there must be a better way and keep the releations on the acual Assignment type... I have another projection which is more advanced which works so there must be something else, I have the code at work so cant post the one that work sadly

Comment: @Anders: The first code will probably set `Assignment.Customer`. The context will put this together (because of "Relationship span"). That's what I meant with my remark below the first snippet. You must not disable change tracking though. I'm curious about your working projection example.

Comment: I updated my question with the query that works.. Your solution works for one level of relation, but I have deeper relations on the Customer that I need and to put them all on the projection isnt a solution that works... sorry

Answer (score 6):

This is [by design](http://web.archive.org/web/20100718113048/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/347543/entity-framework-eager-loading-not-working-in-some-projection-scenarios). `Include` is not for scenarios with projection or custom joins.

Comment: Butare there other ways of including child relations without moving them from the mapped typed to the projection? edit: sorry missed your link, I'll check it out