# EF Group By removes nav properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework, group-by

EF, I'm retrieving a Widget entity. When I GroupBy, it returns with no navigation properties populated, when I don't GroupBy, the nav properties are populated. It's possible my groupby is wrong, but why would the only thing affected be nav properties? 
Here are the queries:

```
List<NewFacilityLimit> group = (from item in tdsDb.Widgets
                                     .Include("NewTslTiers") 
                                     group item by item.AreaId
                                     into groupedPerAreaId 
                                     let maxWidgetId = 
                                     groupedPerAreaId.Max(item => item.WidgetId) 
                                     select groupedPerAreaId.Where( 
                                     y => y.WidgetId == maxWidgetId)
                                     .FirstOrDefault()) 
                                     .ToList();
```

Which returns with no NewTslTiers.  Whereas:

```
  List<NewFacilityLimit> noGroup = (from item in tdsDb.Widgets
                                     .Include("NewTslTiers") 
                                     select item).ToList();
```

This returns with NewTslTiers.  The only difference is the group by.  Any takers on why?

Comment: This is apparently "by design": `Include` doesn't work with projections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917348/include-with-projection-does-not-work

Comment: Is there MSDN doc for this?  The SO question you link to haas a link to an MS Connect page that no longer exists.

Comment: I ask only having already searched for MSDN doc on this!  But it seems crazy that it isn't flagged anywhere.

Comment: I haven't seen anything on MSDN, but there's a blog-post from 2009 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) and a forum post from 2007 (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d700becd-fb4e-40cd-a334-9b129344edc9/) which discuss this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you.  If you post as as answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently "by design" - [Include with projection does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917348/include-with-projection-does-not-work)

I haven't seen anything on MSDN, but there's [a blog-post from 2009](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) and [a forum post from 2007](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d700becd-fb4e-40cd-a334-9b129344edc9/) which discuss this behaviour.